# tomcat auto deploy issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web

I have tomcat server 6.0.23 with default configuration (auto deploy on etc).

how tomcat auto deploy behave right now it some times deploys application cleanly and most of the times it just distroys the application so we are left with restart option

Comment: what do you mean destroys?

Comment: destroys means every source file is removed just META-INF and WEB-INF empty folders are left